# If line starts with a specific string, print only the ip addresses contained within that line using awk, one per line

Tags: regex, awk, match, ip-address

I have the following text output from a command (cmdagent -i) that I am parsing with awk:

```
Component: McAfee Agent  
AgentMode: 1  
Version: 5.0.6.491  
GUID: f0bcc8de-1aa6-00a4-01b9-00505af06706  
TenantId: N/A  
LogLocation: /var/McAfee/agent/logs  
InstallLocation: /opt/McAfee/agent  
CryptoMode: 0  
DataLocation: /var/McAfee/agent  
EpoServerList: 10.0.25.15|epo1|epo1.example.com|10.0.25.20|epo2|epo2.example.com 
EpoPortList: 443  
EpoServerLastUsed: 10.0.25.15  
LastASCTime: N/A  
LastPolicyUpdateTime: 0  
EpoVersion: 5.3.1  
Component: McAfee Agent
```

I would like to match on the line that starts with the string "EpoServerList", and print only the IP addresses contained within this line, using only 1 awk command.

If I use two awk commands, I can make it work, but I know it can be done with only one.

For example:

```
# ./cmdagent -i | awk '/^EpoServerList/' | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' 'RT{print RT}'
```

Which gives the following (desired) output:

```
10.0.25.15
10.0.25.20
```

I've tried the following so far:

```
# ./cmdagent -i | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' '$0 ~ /^EpoServerList/ RT{print RT}'
```

Which doesn't return any matches

And

```
./cmdagent -i | awk -v RS='([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+' '$0 ~ /^EpoServerList/; RT{print RT}'
```

Which returns the version number from an un-wanted line:

```
 5.0.6.491
 10.0.25.15
 10.0.25.20
```

And seems to not consider "/^EpoServerList/" which I am trying to use as criteria to exclude the line containing the version string "5.0.6.491"

How can I match on EpoServerList and still use the record separator with the regular expression to match and print the IP addresses using just 1 awk statement?

This is GNU Awk 4.0.2 on RHEL 7 x86_64, using the bash shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First match lines, then iterate over fields matching the IPv4 pattern:

```
awk -F '[|: ]' '/^EpoServerList: / { for (i=1; i<NF; i++) { if (match($i, "([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+")) { print $i; } } }'
```

Using multiple field separators allows for treating the label as a column, and therefore skipping it when matching for IP addresses.

I know there are many here who will say that awk > grep + some-other-tool, but I find that combo produces far more readability upon a glance:

```
grep '^EpoServerList: ' | grep -oP '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

Note that `-o` and `-p` here are GNU extensions, which I'm using because of your reliance on RHEL.

Comment: This works, but awk complains about the escape sequence for the "\."  
It prints: awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'

Trying it without escaping the "." character works without the warning.

Comment: It also works with a double escape "\\." for the . separator, and avoids the warning and still matches correctly.

awk -F '[|: ]' '/^EpoServerList: / { for (i=1; i<NF; i++) { if (match($i, "([0-9]+\\.){3}[0-9]+")) { print $i; } } }'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Perl solution also

```
$ perl -lne ' if(/EpoServerList/) { while(/\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+/g) { print "$&" } } ' chris_smith.txt
10.0.25.15
10.0.25.20
```

Input:

```
$ cat chris_smith.txt
Component: McAfee Agent
AgentMode: 1
Version: 5.0.6.491
GUID: f0bcc8de-1aa6-00a4-01b9-00505af06706
TenantId: N/A
LogLocation: /var/McAfee/agent/logs
InstallLocation: /opt/McAfee/agent
CryptoMode: 0
DataLocation: /var/McAfee/agent
EpoServerList: 10.0.25.15|epo1|epo1.example.com|10.0.25.20|epo2|epo2.example.com
EpoPortList: 443
EpoServerLastUsed: 10.0.25.15
LastASCTime: N/A
LastPolicyUpdateTime: 0
EpoVersion: 5.3.1
Component: McAfee Agent

$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use perl, or python.  The interpreter that the command will be run in (vRO software component) only supports bash.  +1 though for the perl example.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. hope the other answers have helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[ |]' '/EpoServerList/{print $2"\n"$5}' file
10.0.25.15
10.0.25.20
```

Comment: The only issue here is that the IP addresses may or may not appear in columns 2 and 5, or there may be more than two, or only one.  Thank you for your answer though.  If the output was consistent, this would work well.